# Do I need to release objects that I don't retain?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am keeping a reference to the `example` object but I never use `retain`, `new`, or `copy`.

```
@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *example;
}

@end
```

If I connect a `UILabel` object in Interface Builder to `example`, the retain count is two. But when I don't connect it, the retain count is zero. I would think that I am keeping one reference and the view is keeping another, therefore I would need to release it. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IBOutlet` instance variables are a special case.  In iOS, each IBOutlet instance variable is retained when the NIB is loaded, so you do need to release them yourself.

In fact, you should take special care to release and nil these IBOutlets in `-viewDidUnload:`, otherwise they'll leak when the NIB is reloaded.

*Note that this is actually different from Mac OS X development, where IBOutlets are not retained unless it's a top-level NIB object without a parent view or window.*

For this reason, Apple now recommends exposing IBOutlets via properties rather than instance variables.  That way, the ownership of the outlet is clearly defined.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIButton* myButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSObject* someObject;
```

`myButton` would not have to be released; `someObject` would have to be released.  And in both cases, you're responsible for cleaning up these variables in `-viewDidUnload:`.

Comment: Two more questions and you've got my acceptance. 1.) Why does connecting it to the view give it two retain counts whereas not doing so gives me zero? And 2.) Why do I need to set the IBOutlets to nil?

Comment: You got the retainCount right in your question; one reference is held by you, the other by the superview.  The retainCount is never zero.  If you read zero that means that the variable is nil.  You should always nil a variable after you release it.  That's how you know that the variable is no longer pointing to a valid object.  Without that, you'd have a dangling pointer to an object that no longer exists.

Comment: Last question, so I must always set my IBOutlet instance variables to nil before releasing and I only release for the other objects?

Comment: You should set an instance variable to nil *after* you release it.  It's a general rule, not just for IBOutlets.

Comment: you need to set IBOutlet instance variables to nil only **after** releasing (and set IBOutlet properties to nil in `viewDidUnload:`) or you'll lose the pointer to a variable that you need to release.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using ARC, then you don’t need to release an instance variable, as it’ll be released when your instance is deallocated. If you aren’t using ARC, you should write your `-dealloc` method in `ExampleViewController` as such:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [example release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that if you set `example` manually without using ARC, it is not automatically retained. Since you’re using a nib, however, it *will* be retained when it’s set up.

Comment: Makes sense. But why does the nib retain the object twice?

Comment: It doesn’t retain them twice. It retains the object when setting it as the instance variable. The object is *also* retained by its superview, so you can expect the retain count to be 2 when the view is being displayed, 1 when the view is deallocated or the object is removed from its superview, and then 0 once your view controller is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release them in `- (void) dealloc` if you're not using ARC and there is a property for your `IBOutlet`, and you need to release and nil them in `viewDidUnload:`.

Consider using ARC (Automatic Retain Counting) for you project. With ARC the compiler takes care of retain counts so you don't have to, in fact aren't allowed to. There is a refactoring that will convert a current project.

Comment: why won't you get it? ARC is compatible with iOS 4 as well with minor exceptions.

Comment: I don't have administrative privileges on this machine and those that do are extremely slow with updating software.